# Why i can't run idle in python, while i am connected through putty

Tags: python, c, putty

here is the the text it shows when I try to run idle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/epd/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1406, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1685, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive,    wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: The error is loud and clear: `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`.

Comment: stfw "windows x putty"

Comment: True, the error is 'loud and clear', but this question was obviously asked by someone who has never run X11 programs across SSH before. Just the concept of X11 Forwarding took a while for me to understand.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable X11 Forwarding in your Putty settings.  You can see some screenshots here: http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

This assumes you have an X server on your desktop.  If you're not running Linux this is probably not true, and you will need to install an X server.